# Code Needed to Reset Stereo

Tags: honda, accord, audio

I have a 2010 Honda Accord and the battery died. This reset everything in the car including the stereo. Now the stereo is asking for a code to unlock. Any idea how I establish an unlock code to reactivate my stereo? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Follow what the answer in the linked Q/A says to get and install your code.